# How to retrieve days of week in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, dayofweek

The Days of week is being stored in the following format :-

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"Monday";i:1;s:9:"Wednesday";i:2;s:6:"Friday";}
```

How can I convert it to a readable format and just display - Monday, Wednesday and Friday?

I couldn't find anything related to conversion but a lot of articles are there for storing the days of week using different approaches.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to `unserialize` it. http://php.net/unserialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unserialize()` for that to convert the string into array:

```
<?php
    $str = 'a:3:{i:0;s:6:"Monday";i:1;s:9:"Wednesday";i:2;s:6:"Friday";}';
    $arr = unserialize($str);

    print_r($arr);

    foreach($arr as $day){
        echo $day.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Monday
    [1] => Wednesday
    [2] => Friday
)

Monday
Wednesday
Friday
```